# Haml: How to remove whitespace around text

Tags: haml

I'd like to remove space after name and accomplish final HTML to this effect using HAML:
  John, CEO

```html
%p.about_title_bx
  = truncate about.name,length:100
  , #{truncate about.position,length:100}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `<` in order to remove the whitespace:

```
%p.about_title_bx<
  = truncate about.name,length:100
  , #{truncate about.position,length:100}
```

See [Whitespace Removal: > and <](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace-removal--and-)

Also, remember that HAML is supposed to help with structure, not content. Having a helper method or having that content inline might be a better solution.